How do I pull data from GtR API using search term + python get request instead of search term in UI?
Can anyone help me understand why my code does not work? If you type a search term into the UI at https://gtr.ukri.org/ you get back a list of relevant projects, but using the exact same search term as keyword in my code returns zilch. The reasons for my struggle include: (1) I am new to code and without formal education in logical/technical subjects; (2) I cannot find the correct header format in the documentation; (3) many other difficulties. I would really love to understand why my simple code does not work. If you can make it work I will be amazed and very happy!
Here is my code. I have put "neurotechnology" as my search term because that is the area of interest to me.
import requests

ENDPOINT = f"https://gtr.ukri.org/api/search/project?term=neurotechnology"

HEADERS = {
    "Accept": "application/json"
}

response = requests.get(ENDPOINT, headers=HEADERS)

if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()

    if 'projectsBean' in data and 'projects' in data['projectsBean']:
        projects = data['projectsBean']['projects']

        for i, project in enumerate(projects):
            project_info = {
                "title": project.get('title'),
                "grant_ref": project.get('grantReference'),
                "host_institution": project.get('leadResearchOrganisation', {}).get('name'),
                "start_date": project.get('fund', {}).get('start'),
                "fund_amount": project.get('fund', {}).get('valuePounds'),
                "funder": project.get('fund', {}).get('funder', {}).get('name'),
            }

            project_dict[f'project_{i + 1}'] = project_info

        print(project_dict)

    else:
        print("No data.")
else:
    print(f"Error status code: {response.status_code}")

I have tried looking through the documentation on the GtR API pages and while some things are clear, other things cannot be understood by me. I have also exhausted my personal capacity to extract help from ChatGPT even having fed it all the documentation. I have reached the limit of ideas that I have learned so far in my online course (100 Days of Code, Dr Angelu Yu. I'm on Day 36).

Your code doesn't match the actual structure of the response returned by this API. i.e. The fields have completely different names than those which your code is trying to access. Make sure that you are working with the latest version of the API documentation.
